# How do I get R to read high dimensional data?

Tags: r

I need to use high dimensional data in R. 
I saw this SE community wiki [Free data set for very high dimensional classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/973/free-data-set-for-very-high-dimensional-classification).

I wanted to use the [Dorothea data set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Dorothea) in R, but I could not.

Any help?

Comment: Hi user2227801. I have edited your post to partly clarify what you seem to be asking. Your post doesn't give us any clue what your difficulty was and is currently unanswerable. Further, it's hard to see if it's even a statistics problem at all, rather than say purely an R problem -- [see the help for the scope of topics on CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help). Could you please edit to clarify, and if it's really a question like "how do I get R to read this data", please flag your post and ask for it to be moved to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x <- read.csv("YOUR_ADDRESS/dorothea_test.data", header=F, sep=" ")
dim(x) 
# [1]  807 2887
```

Actually the size of this data is not very big for R, you can easily process it with a normal PC or laptop.

Comment: I have another dataset with a million columns, and R crashes with fread, read_csv and read.csv due to memory issues (I have an 8 GB RAM). Any thoughts on how to read this into R?